# Couldn't stop the function when another function

Tags: javascript

I have this code where when I scroll down it will continue scroll and the same when scrolling upwards.

```
var currentpos = 0

function scrollwindow1() {
    currentpos = window.pageYOffset + 1
    window.scroll(0, currentpos)
}

function scrollwindow() {
    currentpos = window.pageYOffset - 1
    window.scroll(0, currentpos)
}
$('body').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
        console.log('up 3');
        clearInterval("scrollwindow1()")
        setInterval("scrollwindow()", 20)
    } else {
        console.log('down 3');
        clearInterval("scrollwindow()")
        setInterval("scrollwindow1()", 20)
    }
});
```

but with this, it didn't stop the interval. the function only contradict the other function

Comment: look at the docs of setInterval

Comment: and that of clearInterval()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *clear* an interval you need to first assign the interval to a variable. And then you can use `clearInterval(intervalVariable)` to clear the interval you've assigned.

Check out the docs on [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearinterval) to see more examples.

```
var interval = null;
$('body').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
        console.log('up 3');
        if (interval !== null) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
        interval = setInterval(scrollwindow, 20);
    } else {
        console.log('down 3');
        if (interval !== null) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
        interval = setInterval(scrollwindow1, 20);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much! I actually read the documentation but couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

First name your setInterval, for example:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () { console.log('Log') }, 1000)
```

Then use clearInterval function to stop it

```
clearInterval(interval)
```